# onemap api doesnt show points

Tags: javascript, php, json

can anyone help me. when i using this code. the local server doesnt show anything. how to get points on the one map? thanks.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

    //add map with defined center location and zoom level
    var centerPoint = "21090.3965989332,40152.827324621125"
    var levelNumber = 1;
    var pointers="29320.30692133441,29190.96332578225|29520.30692133441,29190.96332578225:http://www.onemap.sg/icons/Hotels/hotel.gif|29420.30692133441,29190.96332578225:D1"
    var OneMap = new GetOneMap('divMain', 'SM', { level: levelNumber, center: centerPoint, points: pointers});
    //dojo.require("esri.map");
    //dojo.require("esri.tasks.geometry");
    //dojo.require("esri.layers.graphics");
    //dojo.addOnLoad(initialize);





    var search = 'txtSearchText';


    function GetCurrentLevel() {
        alert("Current Level:" + OneMap.map.getLevel())
    }

</script>

            <div id="divMain" style='width: 756px; height: 399px;'>

            </div>
```

Comment: Would it work to use the _showLocation()_ method? see it in action in [this plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IMW0T80k0vgKiLnuRI6U?p=preview) - click the two buttons (e.g. _Show Maxwell FC_) to see those points mapped (individually)

Comment: thanks friend. i think my pc is the problem. even plunker example also doesnt show nothing when using my access key and your key. but onemap.sg shows the map without intterupt..

Comment: I don't really see any method in their API documentation for showing multiple points, at least like google maps supports

Comment: oh k. any other choices to do multiple points in onemap